# How to use keystore for ssl in spring boot tomcat server

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, https, keystore

I am new to ssl want to convert our application to support https.
Have achieved this using http11nioprotocol connector. I set the keystore file by using setKeystoreFile(path) method.

But now I want to set the contents of the file instead of path cause my certificate is stored in dB now. How can I set the content of the certificate. Please help.